# Process multiple xml from a folder

Tags: python-3.x, xml-parsing

I have several XML files with identical structure. From those XML files I want to read out some data.

I wrote a script which is doing that pretty fine for one file. Then I tried to extend my script so it processes all files from one folder. I checked several similar questions and tried to use that for my scripts, but I just can't make it work. I always processed just the first file.

Here is my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv
import glob

filenames = glob.glob('XML/*.xml')

for filename in filenames:

    with open(filename, 'r') as content:

        tree = ET.parse(content)
        root = tree.getroot()

        Report_data = open('report.csv', 'w')

        with Report_data:
            csvwriter = csv.writer(Report_data)
            report_head = []
            report_head.append('DocumentId')
            report_head.append('AgreementId')
            report_head.append('Category')
            report_head.append('Doctype')
            csvwriter.writerow(report_head)

           max = len(root[4])
           i = 0

           while i < max:
               report = []
               docid = root[4][i][0].text
               report.append(docid)
               agreementId = root[4][i][3][0][1].text
               report.append(agreementId)
               category = root[4][i][3][2][1].text
               report.append(category)
               docType = root[4][i][3][6][1].text
               report.append(docType)
               csvwriter.writerow(report)
               i = i + 1
```

If I open the report.csv, only data from the first XML is there. All additional files are just ignored. Any idea how I can fix that? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you fix your indentation so that there is a consistent number of spaces per level? You're mixing 4-space indents and single-space indents. Oh and your `Report_data = open('report.csv', 'w')` and the corresponding csv set up should be before your `for filename in filenames:` loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You did very well in explaining what you've done. Now, to make your question perfect, make it clear with a statement in the end, like: "How can I get this done?". You'll have much more chances of getting the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your tip. I edited the last part accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You override the result after each file, so all files are processed, just only the last is stored

```
Report_data = open('report.csv', 'w')
for filename in filenames:

    with open(filename, 'r') as content:

        tree = ET.parse(content)
        root = tree.getroot()
```

Should fix it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your proposal. I changed that, but now I get the following error message: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: Do you have an idea what I have to change to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue. At the end, my code looks like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv
import glob

filenames = glob.glob('*.xml')

print(filenames)


Report_data = open('report.csv', 'w')

with Report_data:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(Report_data)
    report_head = []
    report_head.append('DocumentId')
    report_head.append('AgreementId')
    report_head.append('Category')
    report_head.append('Doctype')
    csvwriter.writerow(report_head)

for f in filenames:

    with open(f, 'r') as content:

        tree = ET.parse(content)
        root = tree.getroot()

        print(content)
        Report_data = open('report.csv', 'a')

        max = len(root[4])
        i = 0

        while i < max:
            csvwriter = csv.writer(Report_data)
            report = []
            docid = root[4][i][0].text
            report.append(docid)
            agreementId = root[4][i][3][0][1].text
            report.append(agreementId)
            category = root[4][i][3][2][1].text
            report.append(category)
            docType = root[4][i][3][6][1].text
            report.append(docType)
            csvwriter.writerow(report)
            i = i + 1
```